# set a Boolean when submitted in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to set a Boolean field is_rep in a retest model to true when the retest form is submitted. 
Now it is just get added up in a retest model.
Because I want to trigger other events when the request is submitted.

My code

models.py

```
class Retest(models.Model):

semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester)
dept = models.ForeignKey(Departement)
batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch)
date = models.DateField(default=0)
subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
admnno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
reason = models.CharField(max_length=50)
proof = models.CharField(max_length=200)
is_hod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_principal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
notify = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_sure = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_rep = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse( 'retest:retestform')
def __str__(self):
             return self.name
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^retest/retestform/$',login_required(views.RetestCreate.as_view()), name='retestform')
```

views.py

```
class RetestCreate(CreateView):
model = Retest
fields = ['semester', 'dept', 'batch', 'date', 'subject', 'name', 'admnno', 'reason', 'proof', 'is_sure']
```

template

```
<form class="form_horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'retest/form-template.html' %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem you have is exactly. I'm guessing you want to look at form_valid(). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: If this request got submitted it will get stored in database.Then it can be viewed by some other type of user's homepage by filtering.So for notifying users for the new request, I need to set a field true when submitted@Bott0610

Comment: Can you show us your form?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the boolean field to true, when the form is submitted, you just have to handle it in the view.

Submit the form and before saving it into the database just set the is_rep = true.
is_rep is a field which is in the model, but not used in the form.
So, if you want to change that then you have to manually write a view for it. Try to use base view instead of generic views to understand the workflow of the views and forms.

I'd recommend using something like this:

```
class RetestView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ..............
        return render(request, self.template, {"some_context"}

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_data = your_form(request.POST)
        if form_data.is_valid():
            new_object = form_data.save(commit=False)
            new_object.is_rep = True
            new_object.save()
        return render(request, self.template, {"some...context"})
```

Hope you got what you were looking for..!

Comment: You can edit your post to update the details, no need to post an answer for your own question.

Answer (score 0):

form_template

```
{% for field in form %}

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }} </span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }} </label>
    <div class ="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-control">
    {{ field }}</div></div>
    </div>


{% endfor %}
```